# Add a new block inside Orders meta box in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am trying to add a new block inside the Orders meta box from Woocommerce. I know there are three possible hooks to add custom data to the existing blocks.

- `woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details`
- `woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address`
- `woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address`

These hooks are executed inside an `order_data_column` block and that's what I do not want to do. I would like to add a new custom `order_data_column` with my custom data.

I tried it creating a new class which extends the `WC_Meta_Box_Order_Data` and overriding the `output` method but it did not work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a block to orders metabox using the following code (for example):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'additional_admin_order_data_block_after_shipping_address', 100 );
function additional_admin_order_data_block_after_shipping_address(){

    echo '</div><div class="order_data_column">
    <h3>' . esc_html__( 'Block title', 'woocommerce' ) . '</h3>';

    // here goes your code and content

    // Fake content output just for testing
    echo '<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante.</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

> But you will need to change some styling CSS rules *(which is another question)*.